# Как переслать сообщение в телеграмме с чужого канала на свой без надписи ПЕРЕСЛАНО С .... telethon

Tags: python, telethon

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно с чужого чата в телеграмме переслать сообщение в мой канал, но что бы не было у сообщения "Переслано с канала..."
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал написать так: await client.forward_messages(id, msg), но все равно он пересылает сообщения.

Вот код: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикладывайте код и любую другую тестовую информацию не скриншотом, а в виде текста, чтобы можно было копировать, редактировать и чтобы работал поиск. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1447509/edit)

Comment: https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/copy_message может так